# API for extracting blogs and their comments?

Tags: api, blogs

Are there any apis I can use (preferably c#) which obtains blog data and their comments?

Thanks

have a nice day :)

Comment: What kinds of blogs are we talking about? Wordpress? BlogEngine.NET? Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: For what blogging engine? You probably won't find a way to extract data from all blogs.

Comment: which would be the most popular ones? I need the most blogs loaded with information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you can find an api for blogger: http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/

have fun with it